# Why the texture appears only in the first quadrant

Tags: c++, sfml

What's wrong with this code using SFML?

In the code below, I have [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/183Nb.png) (1000x1000) and I want to show it in a window (500x500) using sf::RenderTexture.
However, only part of the image appears in the first quadrant:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window({500, 500}, "SFML Views", Style::Close);

    View camera;
    camera.setSize(Vector2f(window.getSize()));

    Texture background;
    background.loadFromFile("numeros.png");
    Sprite numeros (background);

    RenderTexture texture;
    texture.create(window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y);

    Sprite content;
    content.setTexture(texture.getTexture());

    texture.draw(numeros);
    texture.display();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        for (Event event; window.pollEvent(event);)
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        window.clear();
        window.setView(camera);
        window.draw(content);
        window.display();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[image]

As far as I can understand, the code should generate the original image (1000x1000) automatically adjusted to 500x500.

Could anyone tell you what is wrong?

Comment: I do not know what this has to do with the problem, in any case I use a Windows 8.1 on a common Desktop with I7 processor, and Intel on-board graphics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're facing, in fact, two distinct problems:

#### First one:

> As far as I can understand, the code should generate the original
> image (1000x1000) automatically adjusted to 500x500.

This is not really true. SFML handles the **sprites** with the real size of the texture. If your image is 1000x1000, but you want representing it as 500x500, you should assign the texture to a sprite, as you do:

`Sprite numeros(background);`

and then **scale** this sprite to fit in a 500x500 window, this is:

`numeros.setScale(0.5, 0.5);`

With this change you should view the whole image, but...

#### Second one:

You're messing with the view of the window. If we check [SFML documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1View.php), we can see that `sf::View` expects:

- A `sf::FloatRect`: this is, a coordinate (x,y) - in this case the top-left corner - and a size(width, height)

or

- Two `sf::Vector2f`: one corresponding to the coordinates **of the center** and the other corresponding to the size of the view.

Assuming you want to use the second one, you're missing the first parameter, the center coordinates, but this is not really necessary. If you simply **don't apply the view**, the image should be shown in the whole window.

So you simply need to remove:

`window.setView(camera);`

---

The code I've tried:

```
int main()
{
    RenderWindow window({ 500, 500 }, "SFML Views", Style::Close);

    View camera;
    camera.setSize(Vector2f(window.getSize()));

    Texture background;
    background.loadFromFile("numeros.png");
    Sprite numeros(background);
    numeros.setScale(0.5, 0.5);   // <-- Add this

    RenderTexture texture;
    texture.create(window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y);

    Sprite content;
    content.setTexture(texture.getTexture());

    texture.draw(numeros);
    texture.display();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        for (Event event; window.pollEvent(event);)
        if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        window.clear();
        //window.setView(camera);    <-- Remove this
        window.draw(content);
        window.display();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And my result:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate all of your attention in your response, but `View camera` is there for a reason: I'll need it further because I will move it, zoom it, so this image would be just the prototype of a background.

So I can not remove the view. 

And I still could not make the background appear across the screen using the view. This was supposed to be simple ...

Comment: If you need the view, set as said, with `sf::FloatRect` setting the portion of window to see

Comment: Wow, thank you, all the time the problem was the `View camera` declaration... changing to `View camera (FloatRect(0, 0, window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y));` and removing the `camera.setSize` line solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: You welcome!! I'll appreciate you to accept the answer. this help others to know if this question is solved.

Comment: Of course, I had forgotten, I already accepted the answer, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another option to @alseether 's excellent response, I realized that the whole issue consisted of that bad View initialization.

This way you can also **set the size of the view = to the size of the background image** (1000,1000) and finally set the center of the view to the windows's upper left corner.

As the view is larger than the window size (500,500) it will automatically be adjusted to this new size.

In short, the section to be changed would be:

```
View camera;
camera.setSize(Vector2f(background.getSize().x, background.getSize().y));
camera.setCenter(Vector2f(window.getSize()));
```